# Hiding api url in react/redux application (proxy)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, redux

I am concerned about security of my react/redux application as my api url is exposed to the public inside bundled app.js file. I've been researching this and some developers proxy it somehow i.e. instead of using my api url I can use `api/` whenever I perform calls with libraries like [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) or [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) and it gets proxied to my api url, but this way users can only see `api/` on their side.

I'm trying to figure this out, I assume this is set up within express config?

Comment: I don't understand how there would be solution to hide client side network traffic, unless the server is making a call, any client side calls could be detected in the browser or a fiddler session right?

Comment: Typically the solution is to do it server side or use some sort of authentication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a valid concern.

Typically you would have your clientside code make calls to,  say,  /api, and in express (or whatever server you use)  create a route for  "/api"  that proxies that request to the actual api url.

This way you can obscure any sensitive information from the client. For example authentication tokens,  api keys,  etc.

In express you could do something like this:

```
app.use('/api', (req, res) => {
  const method = req.method.toLowerCase();
  const headers = req.headers;
  const url = 'your_actual_api_url';

  // Proxy request
  const proxyRequest = req.pipe(
    request({
      url
      headers,
      method,
    })
  );

  const data = [];
  proxyRequest.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data.push(chunk);
  });

  proxyRequest.on('end', () => {
    const { response } = proxyRequest;
    const buf = Buffer.concat(data).toString();
    res.status(response.statusCode).send(buf);
  });
});
```

This example is a bit more elaborate that is has to be, but it will probably work for you.

Comment: Anyone can still crack open this file and get `your_actual_api_url`. Bottom line, network traffic will always be visible to the client.

Comment: Not true. This code will be executed on the server. So this code will not be visible on clients.

Comment: Ah, I see now this was inside express. Guess I'm now confused by the OPs question, as Im in agreement any remote calls performed by the server are not accessible via the client, obviously.

Comment: OP's concern is one that arises when building client side apps with Node and a bundler like Webpack or Browserify: everything ends up in the clientside code. Including code that does API calls. It is my understanding that the OP wants to obscure the actual API url from that (client side) code, and using a proxy is one way to do it.

Comment: Hm, I use webpack, but it only sucks up code from my entry point, and not server.js. Oh well, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But if your client side code uses API calls, it will end up in the bundle. Thats why this code above should go in server.js (in your case).

Comment: I might have misunderstood but suppose your proxy api is proxApi, now your network will show your window.location.origin+proxApi=abc.com/proxApi thus exposing your api call to proxy now any user can copy and hit this how will your server identify this request is from client and has to be forwarded or not forwarded?

Comment: Thats a good question. The OP is more about how to not expose sensitive information to your client side application. Your question is more on how does one restrict access to the underlying API. The short answer to that is: if the API endpoint exposes public information, then there's probably no real threat. If it's private or sensitive information, you would most likely need to secure those endpoints with a token based solution (i.e. consumers need to identify themselves first, f.e. by logging in, before they can access the endpoints). oAuth2 is a widely used protocol for this.

Comment: how do i configure this to run on an amplify app?