# Handling / Hiding Endpoint Calls while hosting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, url, netlify

I want to encrypt my api call or say Endpoint from react frontend

Is it possible

For example

```
Backend Api : https://teacher.com/abc/new
```

Which is a post method

I am making the call from frontend
So it shows the call and even the query in url which is vulnerable

Can it be encrypted

Comment: For hiding the backend endpoint you should use redux where you can store the api end points and call the function in react frontend for post and get query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968815/hiding-api-url-in-react-redux-application-proxy  this might solve your problem. @Shubham Raj:

Comment: I don't think you can hide them, you can only try to obfuscate them. However usually your endpoint should be protected to not allow malicious queries. You could implement encryption with a public private key pair. You can then use the public key before sending the request to encrypt the query and decrypt it using the private key. However I recommend not trying to obfuscate but instead just protect your endpoint properly

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood. Does the query contain some `secret` or `API Key` which is not public?

Comment: To what end? This is certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: I am concern about endpoints